# Minimize Total Variation Like L1 Norm Regularized Least Squares

Tags: python, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization, least-squares, convex-optimization

The L1-norm regularisation problem is defined as the following:

```
minimize || A*x - b ||_2^2  + || x ||_1
```

but in my case instead of this usual L1 -norm regularised least-square problem i want to solve a problem of this form:

```
minimize || A*x - b ||_2^2  + || W*G*x ||_1
```

due to the fact that my tables W and G do not have the same dimensions like A I can not change my variables and solve a problem like this

```
minimize || A*x/(W*B) - b ||_2^2  + || x ||_1
```

so that i can use one of the solvers that are available at internet.
So i found an equation which solves the aforementioned L1 square problem, as:

```
minimize || A*x - b ||_2^2  + || x ||_1
minimize    || A*x - b ||_2^2  + e'*u
subject to  -u <= x <= u
```

So as far as i can understand if I use -u <= W*G*x <= u i can solve the problem. But i can not get what shall I exactly adapt to the code. Can anyone help? The code is the following (it is taken from CVXOPT)

```
from cvxopt import matrix, spdiag, mul, div, sqrt, normal, setseed
from cvxopt import blas, lapack, solvers, sparse, spmatrix
import math


def l1regls(A, b):
    """

    Returns the solution of l1-norm regularized least-squares problem

        minimize || A*x - b ||_2^2  + || x ||_1.

    """

    m, n = A.size
    q = matrix(1.0, (2*n,1))
    q[:n] = -2.0 * A.T * b

    def P(u, v, alpha = 1.0, beta = 0.0 ):
        """
            v := alpha * 2.0 * [ A'*A, 0; 0, 0 ] * u + beta * v 
        """
        v *= beta
        v[:n] += alpha * 2.0 * A.T * (A * u[:n])


    def G(u, v, alpha=1.0, beta=0.0, trans='N'):
        """
            v := alpha*[I, -I; -I, -I] * u + beta * v  (trans = 'N' or 'T')
        """

        v *= beta
        v[:n] += alpha*(u[:n] - u[n:])
        v[n:] += alpha*(-u[:n] - u[n:])

    h = matrix(0.0, (2*n,1))


    # Customized solver for the KKT system 
    #
    #     [  2.0*A'*A  0    I      -I     ] [x[:n] ]     [bx[:n] ]
    #     [  0         0   -I      -I     ] [x[n:] ]  =  [bx[n:] ].
    #     [  I        -I   -D1^-1   0     ] [zl[:n]]     [bzl[:n]]
    #     [ -I        -I    0      -D2^-1 ] [zl[n:]]     [bzl[n:]]
    #
    # where D1 = W['di'][:n]**2, D2 = W['di'][:n]**2.
    #    
    # We first eliminate zl and x[n:]:
    #
    #     ( 2*A'*A + 4*D1*D2*(D1+D2)^-1 ) * x[:n] = 
    #         bx[:n] - (D2-D1)*(D1+D2)^-1 * bx[n:] + 
    #         D1 * ( I + (D2-D1)*(D1+D2)^-1 ) * bzl[:n] - 
    #         D2 * ( I - (D2-D1)*(D1+D2)^-1 ) * bzl[n:]           
    #
    #     x[n:] = (D1+D2)^-1 * ( bx[n:] - D1*bzl[:n]  - D2*bzl[n:] ) 
    #         - (D2-D1)*(D1+D2)^-1 * x[:n]         
    #
    #     zl[:n] = D1 * ( x[:n] - x[n:] - bzl[:n] )
    #     zl[n:] = D2 * (-x[:n] - x[n:] - bzl[n:] ).
    #
    # The first equation has the form
    #
    #     (A'*A + D)*x[:n]  =  rhs
    #
    # and is equivalent to
    #
    #     [ D    A' ] [ x:n] ]  = [ rhs ]
    #     [ A   -I  ] [ v    ]    [ 0   ].
    #
    # It can be solved as 
    #
    #     ( A*D^-1*A' + I ) * v = A * D^-1 * rhs
    #     x[:n] = D^-1 * ( rhs - A'*v ).

    S = matrix(0.0, (m,m))
    Asc = matrix(0.0, (m,n))
    v = matrix(0.0, (m,1))

    def Fkkt(W):

        # Factor 
        #
        #     S = A*D^-1*A' + I 
        #
        # where D = 2*D1*D2*(D1+D2)^-1, D1 = d[:n]**-2, D2 = d[n:]**-2.

        d1, d2 = W['di'][:n]**2, W['di'][n:]**2

        # ds is square root of diagonal of D
        ds = math.sqrt(2.0) * div( mul( W['di'][:n], W['di'][n:]), 
            sqrt(d1+d2) )
        d3 =  div(d2 - d1, d1 + d2)

        # Asc = A*diag(d)^-1/2
        Asc = A * spdiag(ds**-1)

        # S = I + A * D^-1 * A'
        blas.syrk(Asc, S)
        S[::m+1] += 1.0 
        lapack.potrf(S)

        def g(x, y, z):

            x[:n] = 0.5 * ( x[:n] - mul(d3, x[n:]) + 
                mul(d1, z[:n] + mul(d3, z[:n])) - mul(d2, z[n:] - 
                mul(d3, z[n:])) )
            x[:n] = div( x[:n], ds) 

            # Solve
            #
            #     S * v = 0.5 * A * D^-1 * ( bx[:n] - 
            #         (D2-D1)*(D1+D2)^-1 * bx[n:] + 
            #         D1 * ( I + (D2-D1)*(D1+D2)^-1 ) * bzl[:n] - 
            #         D2 * ( I - (D2-D1)*(D1+D2)^-1 ) * bzl[n:] )

            blas.gemv(Asc, x, v)
            lapack.potrs(S, v)

            # x[:n] = D^-1 * ( rhs - A'*v ).
            blas.gemv(Asc, v, x, alpha=-1.0, beta=1.0, trans='T')
            x[:n] = div(x[:n], ds)

            # x[n:] = (D1+D2)^-1 * ( bx[n:] - D1*bzl[:n]  - D2*bzl[n:] ) 
            #         - (D2-D1)*(D1+D2)^-1 * x[:n]         
            x[n:] = div( x[n:] - mul(d1, z[:n]) - mul(d2, z[n:]), d1+d2 )\
                - mul( d3, x[:n] )

            # zl[:n] = D1^1/2 * (  x[:n] - x[n:] - bzl[:n] )
            # zl[n:] = D2^1/2 * ( -x[:n] - x[n:] - bzl[n:] ).
            z[:n] = mul( W['di'][:n],  x[:n] - x[n:] - z[:n] ) 
            z[n:] = mul( W['di'][n:], -x[:n] - x[n:] - z[n:] ) 

        return g

    return solvers.coneqp(P, q, G, h, kktsolver = Fkkt)['x'][:n]
```

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance

Comment: btw indentation is broken in `l1regls` function.

Comment: [copied your code: **check this**](http://codepad.org/9xdu699X)

Comment: Fixed sorry it was missing the import lines and everything has changed indentation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is given by:

$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \frac{1}{2} {\left| \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{b} \right|}*{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left| \boldsymbol{D} \boldsymbol{x} \right|}*{1} $$

[image]

If the linear operator $\boldsymbol{D}$ is the derivative operator then the problem is known as [Total Variation Deblurring](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/75554).

You will find many variations on how to solve it.
One which is a consensus to be effective is using the ADMM framework.
It is pretty fast and robust while having a single parameter.

In practice, the matrices $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{D}$ have some structure (Blurring Kernel, Derivative Operator, Covariance, etc...). Exploiting it improves the computational efficiency.

I implemented in Julia a generic (Arbitrary $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{D}$) ADMM for the problem above:

[image]

As can be seen, it is very efficient to solve the problem.

The Julia code is available at my [StackOverflow Q28768668 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `StackOverflow\Q28768668` folder).