# Solving Image Inverse Problem with Gradient Smoothness Regularization

Tags: image-processing, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent, least-squares, convex-optimization

I have a noisy image Y and known kernel H. I need to estimate a denoised image X such that it gradient of X is also minimised.

J= ||Y-HX||^2+ Alpha* Smoothness constraint(X);

Smoothness constraint=  L1norm(|| Grad(X) ||)

how do i estimate the gradient of second term involving smoothness.

Help me on understanding the update rule for x; I only know the gradient for first term.

Comment: You need to tell us the form of the smoothness constraint.

Comment: Smoothness constraint= L1norm(|| Grad(X) ||)

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem as in [Minimize Total Variation Like L1 Norm Regularized Least Squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768668).

What you can do, since you operators are given by a convolution kernels is one of 2:

1. Build the kernel matrices.
   See [Generate the Matrix Form of 2D Convolution Kernel](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17418).
   The matrices are large and sparse. Solvers should be able to take advantage of their properties.
2. Define the operators for multiplication (Convolution) and transposed multiplication (Correlation).
   See [Solving inverse problem using black box implementation of the kernel](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/87500). Then the solution to linear system will be done iteratively by solvers which require no direct solution of linear equation.